# run tcsh but bash started instead

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csh, tcsh

I tried to start a tcsh on my Fedora 7 (default shell is bash)

```
[ss@ssvm ~]$ tcsh
[ss@ssvm ~]$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

As you see, another bash shell started.

I looked at the tcsh file:

```
[ss@ssvm ~]$ ll /bin/tcsh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 345348 2007-02-26 23:58 /bin/tcsh
[ss@ssvm ~]$ ll /bin/csh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2010-03-07 13:13 /bin/csh -> tcsh
```

It is not a link (but csh is). I don't understand why this is happening. Please let me know if you have ideas or you require further information. Thanks!

XM

Comment: tsh doesn't run because it realizes how awesome bash is and tries to hide its shame.

Comment: Then it forgot to change its binary to a link to bash so it won't bother any more...

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: the `SHELL` environment variable represents the default shell for your user profile, not the shell you are currently talking to.  It is used by programs that spawn subshells.

Alternately, check your `.cshrc` for an `exec bash` command.  I used to do that at a site where users were not allowed to change their default shell from csh.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. I misunderstood the usage of $SHELL. There is no 'exec bash' in the rc files. Actually tcsh was started :) I used "echo $0" to check it and it is tcsh indeed.

Answer (score 0):

`tcsh` sets a lower-case variable named `shell`:

```
prompt> echo $shell
/usr/bin/tcsh
```

Comment: Also, `ps` will tell you what's running.

Answer (score 0):

try executing echo $0 which will give your current shell name. refer this for more [information on changing shells](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/change-login-shell-from-bash-to-sh-csh-ksh-tcsh/)